# How to output the differences between 2 columns

Tags: r

I am trying to compare my clinical dataset to another one for quality control. We have 1 column for the accepted trials. However, sometimes we don't accept the same trials. I want to compare the accepted trials and have a new column highlighting the trials either of us did not accept/include.

I accept 1,2,3
She accepts 2,5

Output: 
Accepted difference:
I accepted 1,3
She accepted 5

Comment: Hi, you should provide a sample of your data using `dput`.

Answer (score 3):

The most basic way to do this in R is with `setdiff(mine, hers)` (to know which trials I accepted that she didn't) and `setdiff(hers, mine)` (to know which trials she accepted that I didn't).

This assumes data that looks like this:

```r
mine <- c(1, 2, 3)
hers <- c(2, 5)
```

Does that solve your question?

You might consider providing sample data, if the format and other details are critical to your question. There are certainly plenty of solutions to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `c(setdiff(x, y), setdiff(y, x))`, but I think something like the following would give you richer information that you can modify and extract more flexibly:

```r
# We need dplyr for `tibble`, `mutate`, and `%>%`
library(dplyr)

# Create some synthetic data.
all <- tibble(trials = 1:7)
mine <- tibble(accepted = c(1, 2, 3))
hers <- tibble(accepted = c(2, 5))

# Add logical TRUE for accepted and FALSE otherwise for each person, compare.
all <- all %>% 
    mutate(mine = trials %in% mine$accepted,      # Accepted by me.
           hers = trials %in% hers$accepted,      # Accepted by her.
           diff = (mine | hers) & !(mine & hers)  # Accepted one of us.
           )

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 7 x 4
  trials me    you   diff 
   <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1      1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
2      2 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
3      3 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
4      4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
5      5 FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
6      6 FALSE FALSE FALSE
7      7 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

All I've done is create some logical vectors that correspond to `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether or not `me` or `you` has accepted that trial, and then found the difference, which is either/or, but not both. To just get the values you can do something like `all$trials[all$diff]`, which returns `1 3 5`.

I prefer this method because you can more easily broaden your scope. For instance, you can use `mine & hers` to get agreements, and `!mine & !hers` to get trials that neither accepted.